# empty string retrieve all value in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a users table which contains multiple columns like id, username and password and i'm trying to search for the username, but whenever i tried to input empty string it shows all the row, my question is how can i validate the result when i put empty string there should be no result.

```
<?php

include "db.php";
include "function.php";

if(isset($_GET['keywords'])){
global $connection;
$keyword = ($_GET['keywords']);
$result = searchData($keyword);
}

?>

<form action="search.php" method="_GET">
    <label>
        Search
        <input type="text" name="keywords">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="search">     
</form>

<div class="result-count">
        <?php 
            if(!isset($result)){
                echo "enter something to search.";
            }else{
                echo "$result->num_rows  results.";?>
</div>

<?php
    if($result->num_rows){
        while($r = $result->fetch_object()){
?>
<div class="result">
        <a href="#"><?php echo $r->username; ?></a>
</div>
    <?php 
        }
    }   
}
```

function.php

```
<?php

function searchData($keyword){
global $connection;

$query = ("
          SELECT username
          FROM users
          WHERE username LIKE '%{$keyword}%'
          ");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

return $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please add the `searchData` functions code.

Comment: add your searchData function as well

Comment: Something like `if (trim($keyword) == '') { <no need to ask the database> }`?

Comment: @JoselParayno check the answer bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `required` HTML attribute. The form wont submit if the textbox is doest not have a value.

Like this:

```html
    <input type='text' name='keywords' required>
```

And then you can also put in place a second measure in your php script like:

```php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])){
        if(!isset($_REQUEST['keywords']) || empty($_REQUEST['keywords'])){
             echo "<script>window.alert('Keyword required')";
        }else{
            //continue with execution & fetch db
        }
    }
```

And also use `LIKE %string%` in your sql statement

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 WHERE username LIKE '%{$keyword}%'
```

to

```
WHERE username LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

moreover, read about sql injection, passing parameters like this leads to sql injection.

Comment: how can i prevent it?

Comment: i tried the code above, the output is still the same.

Comment: print the value and see if the value that is being passed, reaches there or not..

Answer (score 0):

just check it before pass parameter in query like.

```
    <?php

    function searchData($keyword){
    global $connection;
    if($keyword!=""){
      $query = ("
              SELECT username
              FROM users
              WHERE username LIKE '%{$keyword}%'
              ");
      $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    return $result;
   }
    return "";
    }
    ?>
```

and in your view I mean Html page check it before printing.

```
<?php
  if($result!=""){
    if($result->num_rows){
        while($r = $result->fetch_object()){
?>
<div class="result">
        <a href="#"><?php echo $r->username; ?></a>
</div>
    <?php 
        }
    }
```

you can  learn more about validation in php [here](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_form_validation.asp)

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_POST['find']))




{




$a = $_POST['id']; 



$b=$_POST['name'];



  if(empty($a)){




    echo "<script>alert('Enter Id to Search Record');</script>";



    return false;



  }




 $query1=("select id,name from college where id='$a' ");




 $result1=mysql_query($query1);



  echo "<table align='center' border='1'  width='500' bgcolor='orange'>";


  echo "<tr>";



  echo "<th align='center'>ID</th>";



  echo "<th align='center'>Name</th>";



  echo "<th align='center'>Manage</th>";  




  echo "</tr>";





  if(mysql_num_rows($result1)>0)



  {



  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))



  {



   echo "<tr>";




    echo "<td align='center'>".$row['id']."</td>";






    echo "<td align='center'>".$row['name']."</td>";




    echo "<td align='center'><a href='#'>Delete</a>




      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;




     <a href='#'>Update</a>



    </td>";





    echo "</tr>";




    }




    echo "</table>";





   }   





 else




 { 





  echo "<script>alert('Reord Does not Found');</script>";





}





}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.